# The context menu in the mobile does not work on long taps.. Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps, touch

I'm developing a project and using the **Google Maps API**.
I'm having a problem with mobile devices.

I'm using [**GMaps.js**](http://Https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/context_menu.html)
The example also does not work rightclick (long tap event)

**Example code - [file gmaps.js:441](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js):**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'rightclick', function(e) {
  if (options.rightclick) {
    options.rightclick.apply(this, [e]);
  }

  if(window.context_menu[self.el.id]['map'] != undefined) {
    self.buildContextMenu('map', e);
  }
});
```

How fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem, **simulate a long click on the point**.
befor:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'rightclick', function (e) {
```

insert the code:

```
    /**
     * Start TIMER open context menu
    */
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'mousedown', function(e) {
        var context_menu_element = getElementById('gmaps_context_menu');

        document.pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(context_menu_element).addClass('mouse_tap');

            if (options.rightclick) {
                options.rightclick.apply(this, [e]);
            }

            if (window.context_menu[self.el.id]['map'] != undefined) {
                self.buildContextMenu('map', e);
            }
        },1000);
        return false;
    });


    /**
     * Stop TIMER, and safe open or close context menu
     */
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'mouseup', function () {
        var context_menu_element = getElementById('gmaps_context_menu');

        if (jQuery(context_menu_element).hasClass('mouse_tap')){
            setTimeout(function () {
                context_menu_element.style.display = 'block';
            }, 0);

            jQuery(context_menu_element).removeClass('mouse_tap');
        } else {
            this.hideContextMenu;
        }

        clearTimeout(document.pressTimer);
        return false;
    });

    /**
     * if we move the map - cancel the opening of the context menu
     */
    var context_menu_with_mouse = ['drag', 'dragend', 'dragstart'];
    for (var ev = 0; ev < context_menu_with_mouse.length; ev++) {
        (function (object, name) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(object, name, function () {
                clearTimeout(document.pressTimer);
                jQuery(getElementById('gmaps_context_menu')).removeClass('mouse_tap').css('display', 'none');
                return false;
            });
        })(this.map, context_menu_with_mouse[ev] );
    }
```